# DocuSign: Signer Tabs are lost when updating an envelope

Tags: c#, .net, rest, docusignapi

When I initially create and sent a DocuSign envelope, I define the tabs where to recipients needs to sign and where the signed date will be placed. This works great with the eSignatures REST API.

When some changes are done in the document (and the envelope status is sent or delivered), the document of the envelope can still be updated. 
With the code below I'm able to update the document and email subject/body. After resend, I get the changes made to the email and document correctly.

In the 'new' DocuSign email the signer tabs are lost and I don't have a place to sign.

What I have tried, is to define the signerTabs again and bound it to the recipient.

Update document and email subject/body

```
envDef.EmailSubject = env.EmailSubject = "Updated documents";
envDef.EmailBlurb = env.EmailBlurb = "Changes were made to the document(s)";
env.Status = EnumHelper.GetDescription(DSStatus.Sent);
envDef.Documents = new List<Document>() { doc };

apiClient.UpdateDocuments(_accountId, envelopeId, envDef);

//resend
apiClient.Update(_accountId, envelopeId, env, new EnvelopesApi.UpdateOptions() { resendEnvelope = true.ToString() });
```

```
Signer signer1 = new Signer
{
    RecipientId = "1"
};
SignHere signHere1 = new SignHere
{
    AnchorString = "/sn1/"
};
Tabs signer1Tabs = new Tabs
{
    SignHereTabs = new List<SignHere> { signHere1 },
    DateSignedTabs = new List<DateSigned> { dateSigned1 },
    FullNameTabs = new List<FullName> { fullName1 }
};
signer1.Tabs = signer1Tabs;

Recipients recipients = new Recipients
{
    Signers = new List<Signer> { signer1 },
};
env.Recipients = recipients;
```

**EDIT**

This is my request body when sending an envelope. The signer tabs are added with **anchorString**, in this case /sn1/. So it seems that the updated document no longer has these tabs.

```
"recipients" : {
    "signers" : [ {
      "routingOrder" : "1",
      "name" : "Recipient Name",
      "email" : "Recipient Email Address",
      "recipientId" : "1",
      "tabs" : {
        "signHereTabs" : [ {
          "anchorString" : "/sn1/",
        } ]
```

How comes that those signer details are lost, but the envelope is resend to the correct signers again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably, it is common in DocuSign that the tabs of the recipients are lost when updating a document.
To solve this I got the recipients with the tabs included with following call:
apiClient.ListRecipients(_accountId, envelopeId, new EnvelopesApi.ListRecipientsOptions(){ includeTabs = true.ToString() });

This result can be placed in envDef.Recipients.

Answer (score 1):

so your tabs, how were they created? manually by dragging dropping in the **tagger**?
You can define them using the API as well. You can GET them for an existing envelope and then "rehydrate" them back to the envelope after you updated it.

Comment: I've added my request body that is used to send the envelope. So how can I get the tabs and rehydrate them back?

Comment: your tabs are very simple, I think you can just PUT them again when you update the document. You can just make a PUT call for the entire envelope that includes both documents, recipients and tabs so you don't have to make 2 API calls (or you can make 2 API calls, that's ok too)

Comment: I added the recipients also to the envelopeDefinition and described the name and email again, but without any success. When I get the tabs of the envelope everything is null.

Comment: what do you mean everything is null? what API call are you making?

Comment: GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/documents/{documentId}/tabs

Comment: GET /v2.1/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes/{envelopeId}/recipients/{recipientId}/tabs

Note the tabs are under recipients not documents

Comment: With listRecipients for the same envelope, I get the two signers, but Tabs is null for both...

Comment: you added the tabs? how ? you need to add them either via API or via UI if you want to have tabs

Comment: Check my edit from couple of days ago. I add the tabs in the body of the API call to create and send an envelope

Comment: ok, and do the tabs appear in the envelope when you look at it at the UI? what I'm trying to figure out is which API call is wrong here, the one setting the tabs, or the one reading them